# How can I use the output of a module that is located at outer level of the caller module?

Tags: module, scope, terraform, output

I'm working with terraform for a while and I didn't face any issues as I always followed a simple structure.
But now I've started working on another project that doesn't seem like it adheres to best practices.

The project structure is like this:

```
> root-folder
   > modules
      > cloudfront
      > route53
      > team1
         > service1
            - main.tf
            - variables.tf
            - locals.tf
```

And what I'm trying to do is, use **modules.cloudfront.some_output_value** within the modules>team1>service1>main.tf file as seen below:

```
module "record" {
  source      = "../../route53"
  zone_id     = var.route53_zone_id
  record_name = local.record_name
  cdn_id       = module.cloudfront.some_output_value   //the question is about this line
}
```

But I'm unable to use it, since the IDE indicates there is **no** such module as **module.cloudfront**.

Does anyone know why I cannot use a module that is defined at an outer scope?

*Terraform version: 1.2.0 (probably this's not related to a version based issue, but anyway.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends from where you invoke the `cloudfront` module.

### Option 1

If you invoke both modules, `service1` and `cloudfront` from the same parent, then you need to define a variable in `service1` and explicitly pass the value:

**`service1`** (Should be splitted into `variables.tf` and `main.tf` of course.)

```
variable "cdn_id" {
  type        = ...
  description = "..."
}

module "record" {
  source       = "../../route53"
  zone_id      = var.route53_zone_id
  record_name  = local.record_name
  cdn_id       = var.cdn_id
}
```

**`parent module`** (e.g. in root folder)

```
module "service1" {
  source        = "modules/team1/service1"
  cdn_id        = module.cloudfront.some_output_value
  some_var_name = some_value
  ...
}

module "cloudfront" {
  source        = "modules/cloudfront"
  some_var_name = some_value
  ...
}
```

### Option 2

If you invoke it from `service1`, then the location of the module in the file hierarchy does not matter. You just have to set the source path right:

```
module "record" {
  source       = "../../route53"
  zone_id      = var.route53_zone_id
  record_name  = local.record_name
  cdn_id       = module.cloudfront.some_output_value
}

module "cloudfront" {
  source        = "../../cloudfront"
  some_var_name = some_value
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can't query outer modules** from inner modules. If you have any variables/outputs in your outermodules that should be used in the inner modules, you have to **explicitly pass** them from the outer into inner modules.